# Google app engine - help in query optimization

Tags: google-app-engine

I have run into a scenario while running query in app engine which is increasing my cost considerably.
I am writing the below query to fetch book names -

```
Iterable<Entity> entities =
              datastore.prepare(query).asIterable(DEFAULT_FETCH_OPTIONS);
```

After that I run a loop to match the name with the name the user has requested. This is causing data reads for the entire books in the datastore and with the book details increasing day by day in the datastore, it is further impacting the cost since it is reading the entire list.
Is there an alternative to fetch data for only the requested book detail by the user so that I dont have to read the complete data store? Will SQL help or filters? I would appreciate if someone provides the query.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. If you match the title exactly, make it an indexed field and use a filter to fetch only books with exactly the same title.
2. If you search within titles too:

   a. You can use [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) to index all titles and use it to find the books your users are looking for.

   b. A less optimal but quick solution is to create a [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries) that reads only the book titles.